# How to make a single array space with a date in it return the day of the week

Tags: arrays, excel, date-format

I'm working on a spreadsheet that will keep track of attendance violations for employees.

I have an array called BoxA and it will be filled with dates. I would like a report to be written where a cell from the array is called twice, but once to return the day of the week, and the second time to return the actual date that is in the cell. The goal is a line in the report that reads:

Sunday, 8/24/2014 John was absent.

Is there a way to format the Array. I don't mind creating a second array based on the first that is formatted differently, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the array return the day of the week when it consists only of dates.

Thank you in advance.

motizer

Answer (score 1):

With a date in **A1,** in another cell enter:

```
=TEXT(A1,"dddd mm/dd/yyyy") & " John was absent"
```